# C compiler supported by Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I'm having a problem finding which compiler can support Windows7 for C or C++ programming.
I had installed Turbo but it does not work in full screen on Windows 7.
Please let me know which compiler will be appropriate.

Answer (score 14):

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2010-Visual-CPP), which is free.

Comment: And because it's from Microsoft you know that it should support the full windows API properly.

Comment: @Matt: Most C compilers support the full Windows API if you have the Platform SDK. The only ones that don't use a different ABI altogether.

Comment: Thats part of the reason I put this comment.  People mentioned some very very old compilers that worked well in DOS or early versions of windows.

Answer (score 7):

GCC from either MinGW or Cygwin should work fine under Windows 7.

Comment: I couldn't recommend cygwin for new projects. It has a lot of overhead.  The MinGW implementation is better.

Answer (score 2):

You can get Turbo C working on Windows 7 with [DOSBox](http://www.dosbox.com/). Some of the applications where I work were made in-house years ago, and only work on operating systems that support full screen DOS applications, which means anything prior to Windows Vista. Since deploying Windows XP on new systems was not an option, I did a little brainstorming and DOSBox came to mind, which of course worked beautifully.

Turbo C is very old however and there are better compilers out there now such as GCC which you can use on Windows via MinGW. [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) is a great IDE which gives you the option of an installer bundled with MinGW as your compiler, an awesome freeware combination.

And as already mentioned, there is also Microsoft's development environment, Visual C++.

Answer (score 1):

C-Free is also a Nice one u can go for it

Comment: An light 6905 KB download for C-Free 4.0 (version 4 is free whereas version 5 is commercial). You can get it at http://www.programarts.com/cfree_en/download.htm

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Qt Creator](http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools/). As a bonus you'll get whole Qt, which is platform independent C++ GUI library.

Answer (score 0):

[lcc-win32](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~lcc-win32/) is a free compiler for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

use Gcc with CodeBlocks, this is the best solution for C programming in Windows 7/8/Vista

Get it from here.
http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/26

But if you want to run Turbo C, you can do it via Dos Emulator DOS-Box
(as answered by Chaitanya)

However I will strongly recommend to use Code Blocks

You may need to switch Turbo C with DOS-Box, if you have to use graphics.h Libraries
(which I found easier, compared to CodeBlocks)